# What are these files like Zone.Identifier:$DATA and how to prevent them?

Tags: windows, mount, virtualbox, ext4, shared-folders

I have an ext4 drive which is available to my windows XP VirtualBox as a shared folder.  When working with files across ubuntu and windows I sometimes see these autogenerated files with `Zone.Identifier:$DATA` appended to the name.  For example, if I have the file

`scite-2.29.msi`

Then I will get a small annoying file like

`scite-2.29.msi:Zone.Identifier:$DATA`

The contents of the file:

```
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```

They seem to be created any time I write a file to the ext4 drive from within my windows virtual machine.  I seem to be able to safely delete them without any obvious consequences.

What are these files for, and if they're useless how can I prevent them from being generated in the first place?

Comment: You can delete existing alternate data streams using `streams.exe` utility available in Windows Sysinternals Suite.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the place to disable them, at least in WinXP.  Run `gpedit.msc` and then configure as below:

[image]

Comment: Nice one - thanks for sharing the solution. I didn't have the "Attachment Manager" entry, but found elsewhere that it could be added by right-click on "Administrative Templates", choose "Add/Remove templates", and add the "system.adm" template. After that I was able to enable the "Do not preserve zone info..." option.

Comment: Just found this having the same problem in Windows 10, accessing an NFS resource mounted in RHEL 7.6.

Comment: Alas, this policy doesn't work in Windows 7 guest system. If some file is saved to the Shared Folder, Identifier file is still created.

Answer (score 5):

That file is for storing an NTFS Alternate Data Stream - it's a feature that basically allows any file to have a number of hidden files inside it.

I think that particular stream is written when you download something from the net - Windows can then display that nice "Security Warning" dialog box when you run it and offer to show you an EXEs digital certificate for example. Going to Properties and clicking Unblock may remove this, and there might be a setting to disable it somewhere in Windows.